# Is it OK to use editable: "readonly" always in free jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Free jqgrid field should be read only in all edit modes in all rows.
Is it safe to use

```
editable: "readonly"
```

For this ?
According to  https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/editable-property-of-colModel-as-function

string  value should used in form edit modes only. However it seems to work in inline edit also.
Is it OK to use it or should function like

```
function getReadOnlyEditable() {
    if (options.mode === "cell" || options.mode === "add" || options.mode === "edit")
        return false;
return "readonly";
}
```

used ?

Comment: Following your posted link `EDIT:` part, it seems ok, no?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only two values are currently supported in inline editing: `editable: true` and `editable: "hidden"`. All other unknown values will be ignored. It means the value will be interpreted as `editable: false`. Thus the usage of `editable: "readonly"` is the same as `editable: "bla bla"` or some other value. The column will be not editable in inline editing mode.

Comment: .Thank you. So function in question which returns different data types ( false or "readonly" ) depending on edit mode should used for future compativility

Comment: @Andrus: You are welcome! The text from the wiki article which you included are written before. At the time (in version 4.8.0) `"readonly"` and `"hidden"` was supported only in form editing. Later (in version 4.11.0) I included support of `editable: "hidden"` in inline editing for sending the data from non-editable columns to *remote* server. The usage of function as the value of `editable` exist starting with version 4.8. The code which you included is not required, I wanted just show the existence of `options.mode`. It could consider to implement `editable: "disabled"` in inline editing too.